# Attempting to import a package exported by another plugin. Import doesn't resolve.

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to make a plugin for eclipse, I had to migrate some code that was being duplicated between a similar project and my own to a new project. In the new project I set the package I needed to be exported via the manifest file. Adding this exported package as a dependency works and the option to import it even shows up in the little "quick fix" box.

When I add the import declaration an error occurs and it says that the import cannot be resolved. I'm a little perplexed because it is a local project and the exported package can be added as a dependency without an issues and the tooltip popup tells me to import this package but then cannot resolve the dependency?

Here is the full error message `The import de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis.core cannot be resolved`

Here is the manifest for the plugin that is exporting the package:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: archnemesis-core-rule
Bundle-SymbolicName: archnemesis-core-rule
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Require-Bundle: de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis;bundle-version="1.0.0"
Export-Package: de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis.core.chralx;uses:="org.eclipse.emf.ecore,de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis.archnemesis"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

Here is the manifest for the plugin that is importing:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: archnemesis-pmd-rule
Bundle-SymbolicName: archnemesis-pmd-rule
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Fragment-Host: net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin;bundle-version="4.0.7.v20150522-1709"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Require-Bundle: de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.junit
Import-Package: de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis.core.chralx,
 net.sourceforge.pmd,
 net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.core
```

The package I'm trying to work with is the de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis.core.chralx package.

Answer (score 0):

You must list every package you want the plugin to export. You have listed `de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis.core.chralx` but not `de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis.core` which is the one you are try to use.